# Why standard Office 365 Excel Add-in Template in Visual Studio does not work?

Tags: excel, office-addins

I have just created a simple Excel Web Add-in in Visual Studio 2019 with standard template. I didn't change anything in the code. I am using Office 365 Excel Desktop and Windows 10 OS.

I run the project then Excel is being opened. But, When I click the Default "Show Taskpane button"then I have faced an Exception which is "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDA1F415BB (EdgeManager.dll) in Win32WebViewHost.exe: Fatal program exit requested. occurred"

But also, I have noticed that none of Office Store Apps are running anymore.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the add-in you made?

Comment: I have just added the screenshots